# Why are the comment shorthand links not supported for answers as well?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

While composing an answer to [Sandbox style Meta for characters or story help?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/sandbox-style-meta-for-characters-or-story-help)
 I noticed for the first time that the [something.se] shorthand link for denoting other stack exchange sites isn't supported for questions and answers only in comments. I had a good look at the markdown help and realised that there's a whole host of shorthand links that are [only supported for comments](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) rather than being generally usable.

My question is two fold;

- First is there a specific reason we can't have those links supported across all entry modes?
- Secondly if we could have them across the board do people think we'd use them? Because there's not a lot of point having a feature we won't generally use.

Comment: I suspect it's because comments have a low size limit, so the savings in character count matter.  But that's just a guess.

Comment: I’ve always heard these called “magic links” by people like @Secespitus, but that doesn’t help answer the question at all.

Comment: This has caught me a number of times and it reeks, but in the end, I suspect it is what it is.

Comment: Many of the magic links, like `edit`, `help`, `tour`, `meta`, and site-specific things like `mcve` are unlikely to be useful in an answer (except maybe on the meta sites), but are very often useful in a comment. That's probably why they were only added for comments.